# How to remove the value of dropdown one component to another component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular12

Trying to remove the value of dropdown from table component to ooptymodel component. I have used input and output decorator. But that is not working here. So, How to remove the value of dropdown from table component. I do not know how to use a service to get the solution. So, If anyone know
Please help to find the solution.

table component:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() names: any = [];
@Output() deletedName: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

onRemove(name: string) {
this.names = this.names.filter((x) => x !== name);
this.deletedName.emit(name);
}
}
```

ooptymodel component:

```
export class OoptymodelComponent implements OnInit {
dpData: string[] = [
'Maverick',
'Stanislav',
'Arxero',
'Feruchio',
'Mavericus',
'Arxiour',
];
deletedName: string;
constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

onDeletedName(name: string) {
this.deletedName = name;
}
}
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-table-data-to-input-property-dhxfq6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html

Comment: sibling-to-sibling communication is easiest done through a service or a common parent.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer: Can you edit the stackblitz?

Comment: This is something you should learn to do. Try google Angular Services or Angular Event Emitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Input used to take data from parent
@Output used for emit data to parent.
but in your code, The order of using the components is wrong.

and callFun() is not working, cause components in angular are encapsulation.

[check this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-table-data-to-input-property-uimxdo)

[input output in angular](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/inputs-outputs)

However, you can use a service and rxjs

Comment: Do not delete ootymodel component.I am trying to change the value from table component. Can you update your stackblitz with using services?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-table-data-to-input-property-uimxdo

Comment: you can write better than this

Comment: I updated stackblitz, check the link.